# Did main function and the other function using the same stack space in C++?

Tags: c++, function, local-variables

```
void fun(){
    int val2 = 0;
}
int main(){
    int val1 = 0;
    fun();
}
```

if `&val1` is `0x7fff55e54a8c` , what will `&val2` be?
in my machine it's `0x7fff55e549fc`, shouldn't it be `0x7fff55e54a88` or `0x7fff55e54a90`?
if not, what will happen when invoke another function in memory?

Comment: It's dependent on almost everything that you haven't specified.

Comment: You cannot rely on anything here. If an optimizer inlines the function, they will almost certainly share the same stack space. The real question is, why do you care? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: C++ is the wrong language for you. You really want to write in assembler.

Comment: @CodyGray ,  because I am trying to test some C++ features.

Comment: @MartinJames, could you explain it more specifically?

Comment: This is not a C++ feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good explain:

1. [Memory Layout of C
   Programs](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)
2. [Linux Memory Layout Test through
   C](http://knavite.blogspot.in/2014/07/linux-memory-layout-test-through-c.html#.VuO4dZN95hE)

Answer (score 1):

> if `&val1` is `0x7fff55e54a8c` , what will `&val2` be?

There's no way to predict it within c++ standard regulations.

All of your functions share the same *stack space*, unless you have thread local variables.

For function calls there may be stack frame operations placed, such you can't predict the relation of how `&val` and `&val2` are actually placed on the shared stack.

There's nothing you can assume for certain addresses according the c++ standard definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has a reserved stack space, and in your case both functions are running in the same thread, therefore both are using the same stack space.

In windows, by default using MSVC each thread will allocate 1MB for the stack, and now here's why that info is important.

```
void func1();
int main()
{
    char abusive_stack_usage[900'000];

    // we are about to call func1, and we only have 100kb left to use in the stack.
    func1();
}

void func1()
{
    // here we use more than 100kb, therefore we get a stackoverflow.
    char abusive_stack_usage[200'000];
}
```

In the following example **we don't get a stackoverflow**.

```
void func1()
{
    //we use 800kb here (available in stack: 200kb)   
    char abusive_stack_usage[800'000];

} // we release those 800kb here  (available in stack: 1mb)

void func2()
{
    char abusive_stack_usage[800'000];
} 

int main()
{
    // available: 1mb
    func1();

    // available: 1mb
    func2();
}
```